# Generated FragmentBinding does not contain my CustomView id

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I'm using databinding in my android project and my dashboard_fragment_layout.xml contain LinearLayout which contain TextView and CustomView:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="ViewModel"
            type="com.example.ui.dashboard.DashboardViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <view
            android:id="@+id/viewCustom"
            class="com.example.ui.dashboard.CustomView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

When i trying to access my custom view via generated FragmentDashboardBinding:

```
mCustomView = mBinding.viewCustom;
```

i'm getting 'Can't resolve symbol viewCustom' in AndroidStudio. And i don't have this problem with TextView, it's accessible from mBinding object:

```
mSomeTextView = mBinding.tvSome;  // all fine, no errors
```

I'm always getting this error with custom views, and the only way to access my custom view object is to do this by old way with findViewById:

```
mCustomView = view.findViewById(R.id.viewCustom); // that works
```

All together:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, fragment_dashboard_layout, container, false);
        view = mViewDataBinding.getRoot();

        mCustomView = mViewDataBinding.viewCustom;   // 'Can't resolve symbol viewCustom
        mTextView = mViewDataBinding.tvSome;  // all fine
        mCustomView = view.findViewById(R.id.viewCustom);  // that works
    }
```

How can i access custom views via generated databinding object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `com.example.ui.dashboard.CustomView` in xml code .

And remove the class in xml code .

Try this .

```
<com.example.ui.dashboard.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/viewCustom"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong view tag. try replacing `view` tag to `View`
Replace your view code to this.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/viewCustom"
        class="com.example.ui.dashboard.CustomView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

Happy coding!!